# What happens when return a lazy val from a function in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I found the following code and I'm not sure how it works. This is Scala code with Play framework.

```
    ## route file ##

    GET /:object      @controllers.ResultsController.resultController(object)
```

```
    ## ResultsController file ##

    def resultController(object: SomeObject) = {
        getResult(object)
    } 

    def private getResult(object: SomeObject): Result = {
        lazy val result = computeResult(object) match {
            case Some(response) => JsonOk(response)
            case None => JsonInternalError(...)
        }
        result
    }
```

I'm not sure when `result` is evaluated.
I mean, the return is something that must be evaluated when used, or is it resolved at the time of return?

The lazy characteristic leaves the context of the function?

In this case, the value is never used, only returned as result of a GET request.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the lazy `result` is evaluated inside `getResult` to be returned. `Result` - the return type of your `getResult` is not lazy and actually you can't define function return type as lazy. If for some reason you really need that computation to be lazy, it probably should be something like `() => Result` or `Future[Result]`.

Also the idea that "*In this case, the value is never used, only returned as result of a GET request.*" is clearly wrong. The browser doesn't understand Scala, it understands HTTP which is a text format. It means that somewhere under the hood the framework has to convert your `Result` into a text form (i.e. serialize it) and it will definitely require evaluating it anyway.

Comment: Note that `Future` is not really lazy, just async.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon, I agree but have 2 comments. 1.There is a fundamental conflict between speed and true laziness. Using `Future` (and sometimes ignoring it) is a viable trade-off in this area. 2.Although I'm not aware of such standard implementation IMHO an implementation of `Future` that only captures the `ExecutionContext` at creation and actually starts evaluation only when some of the relevant methods (`map`, `onComplete`, `ready`, etc) is called will not break the contract of `Future` interface. Still I agree that if this is the route you want to follow, you probably need something custom.

Answer (score 1):

I added line numbers to natural explanations.

```
1  def private getResult(object: SomeObject): Result = {
2     lazy val result = computeResult(object) match {
3        case Some(response) => JsonOk(response)
4        case None => JsonInternalError(...)
5     }
6     result
7  }
```

1. It resolves on the line `6`. So it returns the actual value from the method `getResult`
2. The `lazy` use `synchronized` lock inside. `lazy` always verify if the variable already resolved.
3. The `result` variable is local and always used and used only once. So no sense in `lazy`.

In your example, according to the points "2" and "3"  `lazy` slows down the program. It also can lead to potential deadlocks on lines `2`, `3`, `4`.  For more datils look the "Scenario 3: Deadlock in combination with synchronization" in this article https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/02/lazy-vals-scala-look-hood/.

My advice is to remove the `lazy` here.